# How to extract innerHTML using the PHP Dom

Tags: php, dom, innerhtml, nodevalue

I'm currently using nodeValue to give me HTML output, however it is stripping the HTML code and just giving me plain text. Does anyone know how I can modify my code to give me the inner HTML of an element by using it's ID?

```
function getContent($url, $id){

// This first section gets the HTML stuff using a URL
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// This second section analyses the HTML and outputs it
$newDom = new domDocument;
$newDom->loadHTML($html);
$newDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$newDom->validateOnParse = true;

$sections = $newDom->getElementById($id)->nodeValue;
echo $sections;


}
```

Comment: What does the code do now? (what's in `$sections`?)

Comment: Have you tried $sections = $newDom->getElementById($id)->saveHTML(); ?

Comment: http://ru2.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php $newDom->saveHTML($newDom->getElementById($id));

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$sections = $newDom->saveXML($newDom->getElementById($id));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php

If you have PHP 5.3.6, this might also be an option:

```
$sections = $newDom->saveHTML($newDom->getElementById($id));
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php

Comment: Hey Martin, that was terrific. Worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have modify the code, and it's working fine for me. Please find below the code

```
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $newDom = new domDocument;
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $newDom->loadHTML($html);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
    $newDom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $newDom->validateOnParse = true;

    $sections = $newDom->saveHTML($newDom->getElementById('colophon'));   
    echo $sections;
```